# After I use rvm implode to uninstall rvm, it's still fully functional

Tags: ruby, rvm, uninstallation

I'm fairly new to coding and I recently came back to it after installing Homebrew and RVM months ago. Now I can't update RVM or update to the newest version of ruby through RVM so I wanted to uninstall it completely and then reinstall the newest versions from scratch. However when I run rvm implode, it doesn't seem to do anything. I can still write commands for RVM and they work. I want to completely remove all traces of RVM. What do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you reloaded your terminal instance?

After running `rvm implode` you will need to run `source ~/.bash_profile` if you want to keep using your current session.

EDIT: @Rejam states that he also had to remove the RVM associated lines in his dotfiles, specifically: `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, and `.zshrc`

Comment: It says "permission denied." Also, what does that command do?

Comment: It just reloads your `.bash_profile`. Did you do a systemwide install of RVM by chance? You could try `rvmsudo rvm implode`. If that fails, try [this script(https://gist.github.com/adam-allidina/9d36eabd38fea4650ec6) which is what is [recommended by the RVM team](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: I eventually figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @ReJam It might be nice to indicate what you figured out.  What corrected it.  From the answer, I suppose we could all assume that it was the `rvm implode` and the `source` command in this answer.  But you imply there is more to it.

Comment: @vgoff It wasn't. I had to go into the .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile, and .zshrc files and remove the lines of code that pertained to RVM in them. Sorry, I'm still new to StackOverflow. I will make sure to post my solutions from now on!

Comment: No problem.  Just want to give the full story to others that may have the same issue.